# Include Image in Managed Burn BootstrapperApplication

Tags: wpf, wix, burn, wix3.8

I'm working on an installer with wix using Burn and a custom bootstrapper application. Everything works fine, but i fail to include a simple image into my application UI.

I include the Image into my UI like this:

```
<Image Source="logo.jpg" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,0,20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250"/>
```

It shows normal in the designer. I reduced the interface to nothing but the image to exclude other possible errors.

I also added the Image as a payload in the bundle

```
<Payload SourceFile="..\BootstrapperApplication\logo.jpg"/>
```

If i start the installer the file appears in the temp folder of the installation.

I tried different approaches like adding is as a static ressource, changing the build actions for the image but cant figure out how to do it right.

Comment: did you find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the [WixBA source code](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/Setup/WixBA) to see how the WiX installer does it.  It seems to embed the images as resources:

XAML:

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Source="resources\legal.png"/>
```

CSProj:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Resource Include="Resources\exit.png" />
  <Resource Include="Resources\gear.png" />
  <Resource Include="Resources\legal.png" />
  <Resource Include="Resources\news.png" />
  <Resource Include="Resources\wrench.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks, i somehow didnt thought about checking the source code.